# Is there a reason for `iterate` to start with original element?

Tags: haskell

I sometimes use [iterate](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.14/base-4.8.2.0/src/GHC-List.html#iterate) but I rarely need the 
argument in the resulting list.

From the documentation:

```
iterate f x == [x, f x, f (f x), ...]
```

Although I can `drop 1` it, I wonder whether there exists a good reason (maybe a free theorem) independent from implementation for designing basic functions like this one.

Comment: `iterate f x = x : iterate f (f x)` by your own suggestion.

Comment: That's what the Haskell report says: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-22800020

Comment: Conventionally, `f^0 = id`.

Comment: Can you give examples of use cases where you want to drop the argument? Most examples I can think of, you'd want to keep it.

Answer (score 15):

When talking about iterated function application, it is convenient to define `f^0 == id`, so that identities like `f^m(f^n(x)) == f^(m+n)(x)` hold
for all natural numbers `m` and `n`.

With that definition in mind, `iterate` satisfies the following identity by including the argument first:

```
iterate f x !! n == f^n x
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have an output of `iterate f x`, you can easily get that thing you want. But if you only have `[f x, f (f x),...]`, then you can't get `iterate f x`, you need to know more — like, know original `x`. So, dropping `x` in front means losing information for no good reason.

Comment: The OP isn't asking if it is safe to drop the first element of the return value; he's asking why `iterate f x` includes `x` as the first value in the first place.

Comment: And that's exactly what I am answering.

Comment: Of course, this argument could be made to include the input of every function in its output.  `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> ([a], [b])`