# iterate and map

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use `iterate` and `map` together but I'm stuck.

I have a list of possible positions and an initial position:

```
legal = [(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0)]
initpos = (1,1)
```

And a function:

```
addTupple::(Int,Int)->(Int,Int)->(Int,Int)
addTupple (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = (x1+x2,y1+y2)
```

I can do:

```
map (addTupple initpos) legal
```

Which produce the expected:

```
[(1,2),(1,0),(2,1),(0,1)]
```

And I can do:

```
take 8 $ iterate (addTupple (0,1)) initpos
```

Resulting in:

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8)]
```

But what if I'd like to combine map and iterate to obtain the following result:

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,1),(1,0),(1,-1),(1,-2),(1,-3),(1,-4),(1,-5),(1,-6),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(7,1),(8,1),(1,1),(0,1),(-1,1),(-2,1),(-3,1),(-4,1),(-5,1),(-6,1)]
```

which is the result of :

```
l1 = take 8 $ iterate (addTupple (0,1)) initpos
l2 = take 8 $ iterate (addTupple (0,-1)) initpos
l3 = take 8 $ iterate (addTupple (1,0)) initpos
l4 = take 8 $ iterate (addTupple (-1,0)) initpos
l1 ++ l2 ++ l3 ++ l4
```

I can't figure it out. Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Ps: I also don't understand why `take 8 $ iterate` returns the initial pos `(1,1)`

Comment: With respect to your P.S., cf. [*Is there a reason for \`iterate\` to start with original element?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39256410/2751851)

Comment: Very interesting thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can use here is a [`concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap): it *concatenates* the lists that are obtained by applying the function. So:

```
concatMap (\x -> (take 8 $ iterate (addTupple x) initpos)) legal
```

Here we thus introduce a *lambda-expression* which maps every element `x` of `legal` to `take 8 $ iterate (addTupple x initpos)`. All these lists are then concatenated together.

```
Prelude> concatMap (\x -> (take 8 $ iterate (addTupple x) initpos)) legal
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,1),(1,0),(1,-1),(1,-2),(1,-3),(1,-4),(1,-5),(1,-6),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(7,1),(8,1),(1,1),(0,1),(-1,1),(-2,1),(-3,1),(-4,1),(-5,1),(-6,1)]
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want the initial value to be returned (by the `iterate`), you can use `tail` to ignore the "head" of the list:

```
concatMap (\x -> (take 8 $ tail $ iterate (addTupple x) initpos)) legal
```

This constructs:

```
Prelude> concatMap (\x -> (take 8 $ tail $ iterate (addTupple x) initpos)) legal
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(1,0),(1,-1),(1,-2),(1,-3),(1,-4),(1,-5),(1,-6),(1,-7),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(7,1),(8,1),(9,1),(0,1),(-1,1),(-2,1),(-3,1),(-4,1),(-5,1),(-6,1),(-7,1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use your solution but got `Couldn't match expected type ‘[b]’ with actual type ‘a0 -> [a0]’ Probable cause: ‘iterate’ is applied to too few arguments` and `Couldn't match type ‘(Int, Int)’ with ‘a0 -> a0’ Expected type: a0 -> a0 Actual type: (Int, Int) Possible cause: ‘addTupple’ is applied to too many arguments` Could you help again? Cheers

Comment: Quick and efficient! I would upvote agian if I could. Thanks! Any idea for the fact that the initial pos is returned by iterate?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly different way of looking at the problem -- the end result will be essentially the same as in [Willem Van Onsem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43428645/2751851).

Let's begin by noting that `iterate` is a function that modifies functions -- it turns an `a -> a` function into one that produces an infinite list:

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

That being so, starting from...

```
map (\move -> addTuple move initpos) legal
```

... and modifying the function being applied to `initpos` with `iterate`...

```
map (\move -> (iterate (addTuple move)) initpos) legal
-- Alternatively: map (\move -> iterate (addTuple move) initpos) legal
```

... will give you a list of infinite lists, one per pair in `legal`. We can compose with `take 8` to cut down the infinite lists...

```
map (\move -> (take 8 . iterate (addTuple move)) initpos) legal
-- Alternatively: map (\move -> take 8 $ iterate (addTuple move) initpos) legal
```

.. and flatten the resulting list of finite lists with `concat`:

```
concat $ map (\move -> (take 8 . iterate (addTuple move)) initpos) legal
```

Finally, given that `concatMap` is defined as `concat . map`, we can use it instead of this `concat`/`map` combination:

```
concatMap (\move -> (take 8 . iterate (addTuple move)) initpos) legal
```

Comment: Cristal clear explanation, My expérimentations allowed me to obtain the list of infinite lists that you are mentioning but I was using `take 8` before `map` which wasn't helpful. Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: The output is not entirely equal to the expected since the elements in `legal` are the "move directions". and `initpos` the first element. If you run it, I get `[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,8),(0,-1),...]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Indeed -- that remark is more relevant that I thought of on a first reading of the question. Answer adjusted accordingly.